# Windows 10: setup or store app

Tags: windows-10, skype, dropbox, setup

There are several applications, which can be installed via the official setup or via the Windows Store as app. The applications differ and there is usually no hint which version is to be preferred over the other (examples: Skype, Dropbox).

I am usually installing the setup version. Are there any advantages with installing the Windows Store app?

Comment: This question seems to be seeking highly opinionated answers.  Wether the UWP version of Dropbox or Skype is better then the Win32 version of Dropbox or Skype is up to the beholder.  Which version is preferred is left to you, the user, of either Dropbox or Skype.

Comment: Maybe I did not make my point very clear. My question is not "which version do you like better?" but "Is there a technical reason to choose setup over store app or vice versa?"

Comment: If your question is only about Skype an Dropbox that is potentially on topic, if its any application, that is extremely broad, and you should narrow the scope down.

Comment: Let's narrow the scope down to these two. Let's take Skype to make it even narrower. It is from Microsoft and I cannot find any hint why one could / should be better than the other and which is to be preferred. Besides that I cannot understand that they even offer two versions for Windows 10 (they could link the setup to the Windows Store).

Comment: The UWP version of Windows 10 is currently only in a preview stage.  So it does not have every feature the desktop version of Skype has.  I am only away of the UWP version `Skype Preview`, and the desktop version, Skype.  What is the third version you are talking about?

Comment: I chose the setup over the store one, therefore I cannot tell, what the store one would look like. So you don't see any differences or advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: What consider an advantage or a disadvantage is very subjective.  I provided a huge different, the UWP version of Skype is not finished, there are features the desktop version has that it does not.  I won't be be providing my opinion, for the reasons I have already stated, you should spend some time to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Windows store apps tend to be geared more towards touch screen, while regular applications are for stantard desktop style.